# Problemas de configuración GXquery

Tags: genexus, genexus15

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
instale la versión del GXquery 4.0 update 8, pero al tratar de arrancarlo en mi IIS10 me sale este error, quisiera saber cual puede ser la causa.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto. Parece ser que instalaste algo mal en tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

seguramente te falta configurar el application pool asociado a la webapp GXquery40 para que permita ejecutar binarios en 32 bits. Vas a las propiedades avanzadas del application pool y configuras la propiedad "Enable 32-Bit Applications" con el valor True.

Saludos.